# MUI TextField does not work correctly with voisce input

Tags: reactjs, formik

In my React app I have MUI TextField which now works perfectly with Formik. However, would like to use it also as field for voice input.

TextField:

```
<TextField        
            required
            id="city_name_input"
            size="small"
            label={t("page-weather.add_place")}
            variant="outlined"
            {...fieldProps}
          />
```

fieldProps here is returned value of getFieldProps Formik's method :

```
{name: "city",
value: "",
onChange:... ,
onBlur... ,
}
```

So, as I said, it works with normal text input method.

Now, to use speech I took react-speech-recognition:

```
const { listen, listening, stop, supported } = useSpeechRecognition({
    onResult: (result: string) => {
      if (result )  foo(result);
    },
  });
```

That is generic, but generally well checked in other apps.

And how to combine that all - it is a question.

Attempt 1.

1. Added to TextField ref (in fact inputRef to be inline with documentation):

```
const textFieldRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

<TextField
            inputRef={textFieldRef}
            required
            id="city_name_input"
            size="small"
            label={t("page-weather.add_place")}
            variant="outlined"
            {...fieldProps}
          />
```

and following to speech function (in place of foo):

```
if (result && textFieldRef.current) textFieldRef.current.value = result;
```

Effect:
Typing still OK,
When told sample text, it appears in input box, but when submit function clicked, I get result frim Formik validation that the collected value is "". Moreover, the text appears and the field legend does not move up as usual when just typing,

Attempt 2

Read some sources that reccomend rewrite it to state-controlled component. So:
added

```
 const [told, setTold] = useState<string>("")
```

foo function now:

```
 if (result) setTold(result);
```

and

```
<TextField
            required
            id="city_name_input"
            size="small"
            label={t("page-weather.add_place")}
            variant="outlined"
            {...fieldProps}
            value={told? told: ''}
          />
```

Effect:
Now it is visually OK (field legend moves up) but still does not validate as above

Attempt 3

Same as above, with explicit state setting on input changes

```
<TextField
            inputRef={textFieldRef}
            required
            id="city_name_input"
            size="small"
            label={t("page-weather.add_place")}
            variant="outlined"
            {...fieldProps}
            value={told ? told : ""}
            onChange={e => {
              setTold(e.target.value);
            }}
          />
```

Effect: as in attempt 2

Could someone tell me the solution?

I have applied this type of dual-action field in two other cases, but in both of them based on regular HTML input.

Here I would like to keep MUI and Formik as well